# Is there another way to sequentially click all web elements in a list?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to sequentially click through web elements on a page https://www.virginmobile.ca/en/phones/phone-details.html#!/xsiphone/Grey/64/TR20. There are 4 or 5 'plan types' on the page such as Diamond plus plan, Diamond plan, goled plan, etc that I am trying to click on so that the plans below it load however it seems to be stuck on the Diamond plus plan and the bring your own phone plan. Sometimes it will iterate through some of the plan types but skip others. I have used this code in the past however it no longer behaves as I would like it to. I was hoping to be able to click on every plan type (in order) and wait one second (already done) then continue onto the next plan type. Action chains are my go to along with .click() however that seems to no longer be effective.

Here is my code:

```
        planTypeRawList = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope .phonePriceInner')))

        for planTypeIndex, planType in enumerate(planTypeRawList):
            print("-----------------  " + planTypeNameList[planTypeIndex] + "  ------------------")

            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(planType).click().perform()

            time.sleep(1)

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` or `scrollIntoView` to scroll to the element before click.

```
plan_levels = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'planlevels .phonePrice')))
for plan in plan_levels:
    plan.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", plan)
    plan.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```